# Is there such a word as "akind"

Tags: is-it-a-word

If two things are like each other, they are alike.
But if two things are of the same kind, could I say that they are akind?

Comment: You can say they are *akin* to one another.

Comment: You can say "two of *a kind*" to mean alike.

Comment: Do you see this word in a dictionary or in some writing? Or are you just thinking out loud?

Comment: Etymology shows that *alike* is not formed from *like* combined with *a-*.  So there is no evidence for other combinations such as *akind*.

Comment: This can be solved by a dictionary search.

Comment: @FeliniusRex is there "a" dictionary?

Comment: *blinking* Yes. (Am I really having a conversation about whether dictionaries exist?)

Comment: No, my question was vague. Is there one specific dictionary that is considered to be the definitive source for answering if a word exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google shows no use of "akind".

I think "of like kind" or "of the same kind" convey the meaning you want.

Comment: While concise, this answer did the LMGTFY for a question that didn't.